# Detect anchor in Chrome Extension manifest.json

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension, and i need it to apply a script if the URL is `https://accounts.google.com/........#identifier` But this isnt working
Why?

manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://accounts.google.com/*#identifier"],
    "js": ["myJS.js"]
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For url containing [anchor](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3)(`#`), the web request actually is still sent to `https://accounts.google.com/` without the part after `#`, so your match pattern won't match what you want.

You could set `"matches": ["https://account.google.com/*"]` here and wrap your method inside [`window.onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) listener, in that method, to detect if `location.hash === "#identifier"`.